# Outlook add-in using redemption in 32 and 64 bit Outlook version

Tags: 32bit-64bit, mapi, outlook-redemption

My Outlook add-in is compiled with platform target as "Any CPU" and it works fine in 32 and 64 bit Outlook now.

I want to use `redemption.dl`l in my add-in to extent some functionality. I saw there are two versions of DLLs in the downloaded redemption package (`redemption.dll` and `redemption64.dll`) I want to use similar code below to use the dll in my add-in

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyDll.MyMailItem");
SafeMailItem sItem = (SafeMailItem) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

In this case which dll I refer to my project? `redemption.dll` OR `redemption64.dll` ?

How my project loads correct DLL in 32 bit Office and 64 bit Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct dll will be loaded by the COM system, not your code.

As long as both versions are correctly installed and registered in the registry, your code will work without any modifications. Note however that you will not be able to install the 64 bit version of the dll on a 32 bit machine.

You might want to look into using  [RedemptionLoader](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader) - you will skip COM registration completely, and RedemptionLoader will load the right dll for you based on the process bitness.

Comment: thanks for the update this solves my problem. I've one more question. If I rename redemption.dll to MyRedemption.dll then can I still use  Redemption.SafeMailItem objSafeItem = new  Redemption.SafeMailItem() or Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyRedemption.SafeMailItem") ? Any c# code sample available?

Comment: Both ways will work - in te hformer case, the compiler hardcodes the CLSID of the COM object, and renaming the dll does not change it. In the latter case, you dynamical retrieve the CLSID from the class name, but the end result will be the same. Again, RedemptionLoader is a much better option.